# RMI Program Execution

Tags: java, rmi

> ============Server Interface:Server.java================
>
> ```
>  import java.rmi.*;
>  public interface Server extends Remote
>  {
>  void register (Client cl) throws RemoteException;
>  void broadcastCord () throws RemoteException;
>  }
>
>
>  =============Server Class:ServerImpl.java===============
>
>  import java.rmi.*;
>  import java.rmi.server.*;
>  import java.util.*;
>  import java.net.*;
>  public class ServerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Server
>  {
>
>  public ServerImpl() throws RemoteException
>   {
>
>    }
>
>  public synchronized void register (Client cl) throws RemoteException
>  {
>   System.out.println("===>register Method of Process:");
>   cl.receiveInq();
>
>  }
>
>
>  //=========Broadcast Inquiry==================
>  public synchronized void broadcastCord () throws RemoteException
>  {
>  System.out.println("===>broadcastCord Method of Process:");
>   }
>
>
>  //==============Main Function===================
>  public static void main (String[] args)
>  {
>  try
>  {
>  System.out.println(InetAddress.getLocalHost().toString());
>  Naming.rebind("Server", new ServerImpl());
>  }
>  catch(Exception e)
>  {
>  System.err.println("Problem..."+e)  ;
>  }
>  }
>  }
>
>  ============Client InterfaceClient.java:=============
>
>  import java.rmi.*;
>  public interface Client extends Remote
>  {
>  void receiveInq() throws RemoteException;
>  void receiveGrt() throws RemoteException;
>  }
>
>  ==============Client Class:ClientImpl.java==============
>
>  import java.rmi.*;
>  import java.rmi.registry.*;
>  import java.rmi.server.*;
>  import java.net.*;
>  import java.util.*;
>  import javax.swing.*;
>  import java.awt.event.*;
>  import java.net.*;
>  import java.io.*;
>  import java.awt.*;
>  import javax.swing.*;
>
>  public class ClientImpl extends java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject implements Client
>   {
>
>  private Server mycs;
>  public ClientImpl(Server cs) throws RemoteException
>      {
>
>   mycs=cs;
>   mycs.register(this);
>      }
>  //=====Greater List========
>   public synchronized void receiveGrt() throws RemoteException
>   {
>  System.out.println("===>recieveGRT Method of Process:");
>   }
>
>  //=====RECIEVE INQUIRY========
>      public synchronized void receiveInq () throws RemoteException
>   {
>   System.out.println("===>receiveInq Method of Process:");
>   mycs.broadcastCord();
>       }
>
>   public static void main(String args[])
>       {
>   String url = "rmi://localhost:1099/Server";
>   try{
>   Server cs= (Server) Naming.lookup(url);
>   new ClientImpl(cs);
>   }
>   catch(Exception e)
>   {
>   System.err.println("Problem..\n"+e) ;
>       }
>       }
>  }
> ```
>
> it does not executes completely.......If we close the client program the execution 
>   completes....but i don't know why its not executing properly....it does not throw any
>   exception

Comment: What exactly do you expect to be the behavior?

Comment: As soon as the client is up...it calls the register method of the server....which in turns calls the recieveInq method of the client....which den calls the broadcastCord of the server....this is wer the execution is hanging..... im nt getting why the broadcastCord is not executing...can u pls give me the solution..

Answer (score 1):

Remove 'synchronized'. You are deadlocked. RMI callbacks execute on a different thread from the original call.